# What's the meaning of bold sentence in the given excerpt from the economist

Tags: meaning

The local population in Venice has roughly halved over the past 30 years. **So, over the past two decades, has that of Dubrovnik in Croatia, an old walled city best known as King’s Landing in “Game of Thrones”.** Academics now worry that services for ordinary residents, such as cheap cafés and doctors’ surgeries, will collapse if populations continue to fall.

*In the above excerpt, what's the meaning of- **So, over the past two decades, has that of Dubrovnik in Croatia, an old walled city best known as King’s Landing in “Game of Thrones”**.*

Comment: "So" means "In the same way..." and refers to the sentence before it. It's a short version for "The population of Dubrovnik [...] has _also_ halved over the last 20 years."

Comment: By the way, this sentence is a bit of a chore even for native speakers, and it has a strong smell of the lamp about it. "So" is able refer to nearly any type of thing in a previous sentence. It is only after reading the parallel structure of the rest of the sentence, which effectively eliminates other possibilities, that we can deduce *so* is anaphoric to *roughly halved* and *that* is anaphoric to *local population*. Over the past 20 years, the same thing has happened in Dubrovnik

Comment: @DavidRobinson Done.

Answer (score 2):

By the way, this sentence is a bit of a chore even for native speakers, and it has a strong smell of the lamp about it. "So" is able refer to nearly any type of thing in a previous sentence. It is only after reading the parallel structure of the rest of the sentence, which effectively eliminates other possibilities, that we can deduce *so* is anaphoric to *roughly halved* and *that* is anaphoric to *local population*.

Over the past 20 years, the same thing has happened in Dubrovnik

Answer (score 1):

> **so** (adverb) = "in the same way, also"  [**Collins**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/so)

The population of Venice has halved. So has the population of Dubrovnik.

The population of Venice has halved.  The population od Dubrovnik has also halved.